# Update for loop on oracle take much time

Tags: oracle, loops

I got this procedur to set update of multiples values, but on my test , it take much time and stay on Running Procedure. I have tried to set  ROWNUM < 3 , to test with only 2 ID , but still the same ..

```
    BEGIN 

   FOR device_update
      IN (SELECT device_id
            FROM device where  device_id is not null and ROWNUM < 3 )
   LOOP
      UPDATE device 
         SET positions = (SELECT max(position) from position where device = device_update.device_id)
       WHERE device_id = device_update.device_id;
       commit;
       dbms('done device id :');
       dbms(device_update.device_id);
   END LOOP;

END;
```

The update doesen't work and stay on ScriptRunner (sql developper) ,but when I remove update statement , I keep only DBMS this work in 1ms .

Whats can be the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: on a side note using commit or rollback inside loop results in fetch out of sequence error

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using the loop at all.

This can be done using the single `UPDATE` statement and will be less time-consuming.

```
UPDATE DEVICE
   SET POSITIONS = 'test'
 WHERE DEVICE_ID = (
        SELECT DEVICE_ID
          FROM DEVICE
         WHERE DEVICE_ID IS NOT NULL
           AND ROWNUM < 3
    )
```

Also, You need to check if some other session has not locked the rows or we can say has not committed/rollbacked the transaction which is updating/deleting the same record yet.

Cheers!!

Comment: I use loop beacause instead of 'test' it will be a query who need  'device_update.device_id'

Comment: Nonetheless, you don't need a loop.

Comment: Then also you don't need a loop as correctly said by the Littlefoot.